# Incrementing a variable of type UInt8 inside of a for loop

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation
import Swift

var buff = [UInt8](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)
var index: UInt8
index = 0

for var i = 0; i < 256; ++i {
buff[i] = index;
++index
}
```

When I increment index outside of the for loop it works fine. But when I increment index inside the for loop, like in the code above, I get the following error

```
1
0  swift                    0x000000010ea31fbb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
1  swift                    0x000000010ea326fb SignalHandler(int) + 379
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff832c3eaa _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2094252400
4  swift                    0x000000010cfa09bf llvm::MCJIT::runFunction(llvm::Function*, std::__1::vector<llvm::GenericValue, std::__1::allocator<llvm::GenericValue> > const&) + 271
5  swift                    0x000000010cfa30f6 llvm::ExecutionEngine::runFunctionAsMain(llvm::Function*, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, char const* const*) + 1190
6  swift                    0x000000010ce34d8c swift::RunImmediately(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SILOptions const&) + 2188
7  swift                    0x000000010cb23151 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 13425
8  swift                    0x000000010cb1fad3 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2691
9  swift                    0x000000010cb1c154 main + 2324
10 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff975535ad start + 1
11 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000000c start + 1756023392
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -interpret File.swift -target x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -color-diagnostics -module-name File 
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: the problem is the last loop you are trying to increment it over 255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem there it is in the last loop when you try to increment it overflows your UInt8.max 255.

You have many different options to accomplish what you want:

To keep the loop you will need start your iteration from the second element in your array and increment your var at the same time you assign it to your buff to prevent overflow:

```
for var i = 1; i < 256; ++i {
    buff[i] = ++index
}
```

or use `for in` loop to iterate your array indices:

```
for i in buff.indices {
    buff[i] = UInt8(i)
}
```

Or you can simply initialize your array with a range:

```
let buff = [UInt8](0...255)
```